# Swipe and hold character movement not working

Tags: unity, unityscript, touch, control

Heres my PlayerControl script

```
void Update () {

    foreach (Touch FingerTouch in Input.touches)
    {
        if(FingerTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            FingerInitialPosition=FingerTouch.position.x;
       }
        if(FingerTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            FingerMovedPosition=FingerTouch.position.x;
            if(FingerMovedPosition>FingerInitialPosition)
            {
                charcter.transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
           }
            if(FingerMovedPosition<FingerInitialPosition)
            {
                charcter.transform.Translate(-Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            }
        if(FingerTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            FingerInitialPosition=0f;
            FingerMovedPosition=0f;

        }


    }


}
```

}

The problem here is the player doesn't move when you swipe and hold on the touch screen but only moves when you keep swiping.

Can you please help whats wrong or missing in the code so that the player moves when swiped and held?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works when you keep swiping because you only update the player's position during the `TouchPhase.Moved` event.  If you want to update the player's position even when the user's finger hasn't been moving, you need a default case:

```
void Update () {

    foreach (Touch FingerTouch in Input.touches)
    {
        if(FingerTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            FingerInitialPosition=FingerTouch.position.x;
        }
        else if(FingerTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            FingerMovedPosition=FingerTouch.position.x;
            if(FingerMovedPosition>FingerInitialPosition)
            {
                charcter.transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if(FingerMovedPosition<FingerInitialPosition)
            {
                charcter.transform.Translate(-Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
        else if(FingerTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            FingerInitialPosition=0f;
            FingerMovedPosition=0f;

        }
        else //NEW PART!//
        {
            FingerMovedPosition=FingerTouch.position.x;
            if(FingerMovedPosition>FingerInitialPosition)
            {
                charcter.transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if(FingerMovedPosition<FingerInitialPosition)
            {
                charcter.transform.Translate(-Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to the new statement, the others are all `else if` as well.

Comment: How do i disable multiple horizontal swipe?

Comment: You should store the touch-ID of the tracked finger and compare.

Comment: please have a look here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/113057/75648